# String is too long for Toast - How to display end of string rather than beginning

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ok this is probably a really simple one. I have a string value that I want to display in a toast. For Example...

```
String tempstring = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456789012345678901234567890"; 
toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tempstring , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

The problem I have is that tempstring in my program can often get quite big and the amount of text is sometimes bigger than the toast can display. When this happens the toast displays the text from the beginning and cuts of the end. I want the toast to always show the end of the string but cut of the beginning if the text is too much to display at one time in the toast. Is there an easy way to do this please?

Comment: There might be a better way, but why don't you first determine max string length for toast, then compare your tempstring length against that, then use substring cutting the beginning, and showing only the remaining part that fits in toast? Downside - everytime you will need to compare string length and use substring...

Comment: Thanks but how do you determine the max string length of the toast bearing in mind different size screens?

Comment: As @Melquiades said, you can use something like this `String tempstring = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm123456789012345678901234567890";
        tempstring = tempstring.length() <= 7 ? tempstring : tempstring.substring(tempstring.length() - 7);` to cut the string

Comment: @Regnodulous That I'm not sure, but you could test on few different resolution devices (or emulators) and see if there's a pattern...

Comment: you can use the \n to use another line if you want

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm already using that method to cut the string but  I'm cutting it far shorter than I need to on a tablet screen to account for a phone screen. I either need a method to work out how many characters a toast is capable of showing on a particular screen size or force the toast to show the last text possible. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's quite as simple as I hoped. :-)

Comment: You can probably do some hacky stuff like defining a custom xml for the `Toast` that has a `TextView` inside a `ScrollView` and always scroll it to the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok worked this out myself.

Its not too hard...

The answer is to create a custom view for the toast. First create an XML file like so... NB The important bit to note is the gravity setting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout_id"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp"

>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then reference the view like so from your toast...

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));
    // set a message
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText(themessage);

    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    themessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
```

Job done...

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need. It is implemented in gmail app.

https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/undobar/src/com/example/android/undobar/UndoBarController.java

And so you can do your custom layout of toast, with as much number of lines, as you want, without 
even cutting stuff.

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code. You could also copy and paste the more interesting parts while adding commentary.